# Amazon OpenSearch: limit data loss when solving unassigned shards

Tags: opensearch, amazon-opensearch

#### Problem

Say you have an Amazon OpenSearch domain in the red state due to UNASSIGNED shards. The indices in the red state had 2 primaries and no replicas, with one of the two primary shards UNASSIGNED. Backups are not available to restore all indices in the red state.

#### What I wanted to do

Now, in a self-managed cluster, I would minimise data loss using the `_cluster/reroute` API (`allocate_empty_primary` command) to reroute the UNASSIGNED primaries to another cluster node, retaining at least part of the documents in the index.

#### Why I cannot do it

However, the `_cluster/reroute` API is not supported in Amazon OpenSearch (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/supported-operations.html), and the only option I'm aware of to recover the cluster from red state is to delete all red indices, also losing the data in the assigned primaries.

#### My question

Can you recommend another approach that could reduce data loss?